# How to download SSRS PDF report using Java and URL/REST?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to download SSRS reports in Pdf and other formats using Java and REST API. I tried looking for help in the official documentation but could not find it. Did anyone has came across the same issue? Any help is appreciated.